# Create setup with s/n 

Tags: c#, vb.net, installation

I have a Vb.Net/C# 2010 project that I'd like to distribute as a setup file. During installation, it should ask the user for a serial number. Any suggestions as to how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a question on DaniWeb, more an idea rather than an actual way to implement it: http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread336128.html

Written in VB.NET, this person made a package of code that randomly generates CD keys. It might help with random generation in your project. He stated that he would try to get C# code up some time, but I don't know if he has or will. Here's the link: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/cdkeys.aspx

This thread has a couple of links to MSDN articles and some interesting ideas on the topic: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=472626

As far as I can tell, if you sincerely want to implement a serial key system, you would:

`1) Need to randomly generate keys and store them somewhere.`

`2) Check the available keys every time a user enters one, therefore requiring online access.`

`3) You might even have to use paid libraries, as it's difficult to do this alone.`

`4) Give the user some kind of offline "key-storage" technique, such as Autodesk products do. This means that they fill out the registration and then save a file to their hard drive with their registration information, so they can send it to you later, when they have an internet connection. Be warned, however, that these offline activation systems are very easily exploited.`

I'm sorry I can't be of more help, I have researched this topic, but have never successfully accomplished it!

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Either code everything yourself or i would say use an Installation Builder tool like [Install Shield](http://www.flexerasoftware.com/products/installshield.htm) from Flexera Software which provide such facilities. Even Microsoft suggest it.. however its not free.